# react native axios post the request two times

Tags: react-native, api, axios

axios post the request two times. Firstly, it store an empty data in he database. and secondly it store in the database with the data i've put.

this is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { A } from "@expo/html-elements";
import { LogoImage } from "../assets/";
import MaterialIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import Checkbox from "expo-checkbox";
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, Pressable } from "react-native";
import {
  NativeBaseProvider,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Input,
  Select,
} from "native-base";

const SignUp = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [isCondition, SetIsCondition] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({
    userName: "",
    password: "",
    lastName: "",
    job: "",
    jobCategory: "",
  });
  
  const [isDataEmpty, setIsDataEmpty] = useState({
    userName: false,
    password: false,
    lastName: false,
    job: false,
    jobCategory: false,
  });

  const submitData = () => {
    if (
      inputData.userName != "" &&
      inputData.password.length >= 8 &&
      inputData.lastName != "" &&
      inputData.job != "" &&
      inputData.jobCategory != "" &&
      isCondition
    ) {
      // api
      setIsLoading(true);

      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/chantier237/API/AUTH/st_signup.php",
        responseType: "json",
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
        data: {
          userName: inputData.userName,
          password: inputData.password,
          lastName: inputData.lastName,
          job: inputData.job,
          jobCategory: inputData.jobCategory,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          if (response.data.status == "ERROR") {
            //TOAST THE ERROR
            console.log(response.data.message);
          } else {
            // save the datauser in state and in local

            AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "st_chantier237_user",
              JSON.stringify({
                userId: response.data.data.id,
                isAbonned: response.data.data.is_abon,
                dateAbonned: response.data.data.date_abon,
              })
            );

            props.setStateUser({
              userId: response.data.data.id,
              isAbonned: response.data.data.is_abon,
              dateAbonned: response.data.data.date_abon,
            });
          }
          // navigation.replace("Home");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // toat error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    } else {
      if (inputData.userName == "") {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, userName: true };
        });
      } else {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, userName: false };
        });
      }
      if (inputData.password.length < 8) {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, password: true };
        });
      } else {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, password: false };
        });
      }
      if (inputData.lastName == "") {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, lastName: true };
        });
      } else {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, lastName: false };
        });
      }
      if (inputData.job == "") {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, job: true };
        });
      } else {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, job: false };
        });
      }
      if (inputData.jobCategory == "") {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, jobCategory: true };
        });
      } else {
        setIsDataEmpty((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, jobCategory: false };
        });
      }
      if (!isCondition) {
        console.log("condition not");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <ScrollView className="bg-white flex-1">
        <View className="items-center justify-center pt-7 w-full pb-10">
          <View className="w-32 h-32 mb-2">
            <Image source={LogoImage} className="w-full h-full object-cover" />
          </View>
          <View className="flex-col items-center justify-center w-full">
            <Text className="text-[30px] text-[black] mb-1 text-bold">
              Inscription
            </Text>
            <Text>creer votre compte</Text>
          </View>

          <View className="w-full px-8 items-center justify-center flex-col pt-5 gap-5">
            <FormControl isInvalid={isDataEmpty.userName}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur"
                type="text"
                className="text-sm"
                name="userName"
                onChangeText={(value) =>
                  setInputData({ ...inputData, userName: value })
                }
              />
              <FormControl.HelperText>
                Veuillez renseigner un seul nom
              </FormControl.HelperText>
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                Ce champ ne doit pas etre vide.
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl isInvalid={isDataEmpty.lastName}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Votre nom"
                type="text"
                className="text-sm"
                onChangeText={(value) =>
                  setInputData({ ...inputData, lastName: value })
                }
              />
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                Ce champ ne doit pas etre vide.
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl isInvalid={isDataEmpty.password}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Mot de passe"
                type={show ? "text" : "password"}
                className="text-sm"
                onChangeText={(value) =>
                  setInputData({ ...inputData, password: value })
                }
                InputRightElement={
                  <Pressable onPress={() => setShow(!show)}>
                    <MaterialIcons
                      name={show ? "visibility" : "visibility-off"}
                      size={25}
                      mr="2"
                      color="black"
                      style={{ marginRight: 13 }}
                    />
                  </Pressable>
                }
              />
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 caracteres
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl isInvalid={isDataEmpty.job}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Nom de votre metier"
                type="text"
                className="text-sm"
                onChangeText={(value) =>
                  setInputData({ ...inputData, job: value })
                }
              />
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                Ce champ ne doit pas etre vide.
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl isInvalid={isDataEmpty.jobCategory}>
              <Select
                accessibilityLabel="Selectionner votre categorie"
                placeholder="Selectionner votre categorie"
                className="text-sm"
                _selectedItem={{
                  bg: "teal.600",
                }}
                mt="1"
                onValueChange={(value) =>
                  setInputData({ ...inputData, jobCategory: value })
                }
              >
                <Select.Item label="UX Research" value="ux" />
                <Select.Item label="Web Development" value="web" />
                <Select.Item label="Cross Platform Development" value="cross" />
                <Select.Item label="UI Designing" value="ui" />
                <Select.Item label="Backend Development" value="backend" />
              </Select>
              <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                Ce champ ne doit pas etre vide.
              </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl className="w-full px-7">
              <View className="flex-row text-center items-center justify-start">
                <Checkbox
                  value={isCondition}
                  onValueChange={SetIsCondition}
                  color="blue"
                />
                <Text className="text-center text-sm">
                  J'accepte les{" "}
                  <A
                    href="https://stcode-portfolio.netlify.app"
                    style={{
                      color: "blue",
                      textDecorationLine: "underline",
                    }}
                  >
                    termes et conditions d'utilisation{" "}
                  </A>
                  et la{" "}
                  <A
                    href="https://stcode-portfolio.netlify.app"
                    style={{
                      color: "blue",
                      textDecorationLine: "underline",
                    }}
                  >
                    politique de confidentialite
                  </A>
                </Text>
              </View>
            </FormControl>

            <Button
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "black",
                width: "100%",
                height: 60,
                borderRadius: 7,
                fontSize: 25,
              }}
              onPress={submitData}
              size="lg"
              colorScheme="black"
              isLoading={isLoading}
              isLoadingText="Inscription"
            >
              S'inscrire
            </Button>

            <Text className="items-center justify-center w-full text-center">
              Vous avez deja un compte ?{"  "}
              <Text
                className="text-[15px] text-blue-700"
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("Signin");
                }}
              >
                Connectez-vous
              </Text>
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

When i click on the button to run post the request with axios, it execute two times. I saw it because they are two new record in the database. The first record which is empty and the second one which contain the data.

Answer (score 0):

**First,**

use the console log to check why your

```
if (
      inputData.userName != "" &&
      inputData.password.length >= 8 &&
      inputData.lastName != "" &&
      inputData.job != "" &&
      inputData.jobCategory != "" &&
      isCondition
    )
```

Let your unwanted condition pass through.

I recommend use

`console.log({inputData,isCondition})` This line will show you exactly where it goes wrong.

**Second,**

I see you have `isLoading` state. You can put it to good use by disable the button if it's true or adding it to your first `if` to block `submitData` to go further if it is loading.